# Deleting files by age

Tags: find, rm

Is there a command to delete all the files in a directory that haven't been modified in *N* days?  I need to clean up some old logs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will delete all files older than 5 days, you can put a `-name '*log'` in there too to be more precise and you might want to specify a `maxdepth` in the find command too.

`find /some/dir -type f -mtime +5 -delete`

Comment: Although wise sysadmins do a dry-run with `-ls` instead of `-delete` to make sure this won't delete anything they wanted kept. Yes, speaking from experience here.

Comment: Speaking from experience, they also check their path. or not, since I once did the `/ some/dir/` version. :(

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh` and `(.m+n)` [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `.` selects only regular files, `m+n` selects files modified more than *n* days ago;
e.g. list the files in the current directory that were modified more than 9 days ago:

```
print -rl -- *(.m+9)
```

add `D` to include dot files:

```
print -rl -- *(D.m+9)
```

or if you want to recurse (and list e.g. only files ending with `.log`):

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl -- **/*.log(.m+9)
```

replace `print -rl` with `rm` if you're happy with the result; though you may have to use `zargs` if you have many files (to avoid *arguments list too long*):

```
autoload zargs
zargs ./**/*(.m+9) -- rm
```