# Shell script to delete all files which are older

Tags: shell-script, files, rm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting files by age](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37950/deleting-files-by-age)

Write a shell script to delete all the files which are "n" of older that current day, where n can be 3days. 2days, or 1 year etc. The above script should only delete files which is having an extension *.log.

Any help on this? Thanks

Comment: We have plenty of questions already about [delete files older](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=delete+files+older). None of them has an answer for your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use `find` command specifing NNN in hours, i.e., 24*number_of_days:

```
find /path/to/dir -daystart -type f -name \*.log -mtime +NNN -delete
```

Comment: Non-GNU users may need `-exec rm -f {} +` instead of `-delete`.

Comment: @user30080 if you find the answer useful, please click on the up arrow above the answer number. Thanks.